# Android ListView, GridView loaded slowly

Tags: android, http, listview, optimization, gridview

In short, in my application has ListView with data from SQLite and images from http url, there is also a GridView as well with data from SQLite and images from http url.
Appears all is well! but when scrolling long application loaded slowly
Tell me how to optimize my application? plz

Comment: Use lazy list http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/964741

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much explained in the Android Training [site](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) by Using a Background Thread and Holding View Objects in a View Holder.  If you want more explanation, you should watch this talk by Romain Guy and Chet Haase - [The World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used some cursor try to close them with

```
cursor.close;
```

and at the end close also the database

```
myDb.close;
```

because every time you scroll the cursors repeat every action that you made they do